# AngularJS: dynamic custom directive with multiple templates

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I'm a Java developer working on a side-project. I've decided to use AngularJS to consume my RESTful webservice.

My **JSON structure** is following:

```
[
  {
    "generatorName": "name1",
    "constructorParams": [
      {
        "type": "Boolean",
        "value": "true",
      },
      {
        "type": "Integer",
        "value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "generatorName": "name2",
    "constructorParams": [
      {
        "type": "Integer",
        "value": "10",
      },
      {
        "type": "Integer",
        "value": "10",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal is to display a specific (for ex. number, text etc.) input field based on the "type" of constructor param and initialise it with a "value". So, if the first generator was selected, I'd like to have something like this:

```
<html>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>

    <input type="number" value="2">
<html>
```

I've read some threads and decided to use custom directive inside my **loop**:

```
<p ng-repeat="param in selectedGenerator.constructorParams">
      <constructor-param param="{{param}}"></constructor-param>
</p>
```

Here's my **custom directive**:

```
app.directive("constructorParam", function() {
    return {
        scope : {
            param : '@'
        },
        templateUrl : '/html_templates/constructor_param_template.html'
    };
});
```

And here's **template**:

```
<div ng-switch="{{param.type}}">
    <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
        <input type="number" ng-attr-name="{{param.type}}" min="0" ng-attr-value="{{param.value}}">
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
        <select ng-if="{{param.value}}" ng-attr-name="{{param.type}}">
            <option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-if="!{{param.value}}" ng-attr-name="{{param.type}}">
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="false">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="String">
        <input type="text" ng-attr-name="{{param.type}}" ng-attr-value="{{param.value}}">
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="Double">
        <input type="number" ng-attr-name="{{param.type}}" step="0.01" min="0" ng-attr-value="{{param.value}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

These don't work. I can see in the Chrome developer's tools that the directive is run, but it doesn't provide any visible output. My questions are:

1) Do I pass the param object correctly in the custom directive element?

2) I'm not sure about the `scope` of the directive - I've also tried `param : '=param'` - it doesn't work either...

3) How should I read the passed object's properties in the template? I've tried: `value="{{param.type}}"`, `value={{param.type}}` and `ng-attr-value="{{param.value}}"`. None works, but there could be completely different cause to that...

4) Can I use prefix "ng-attr-" for all such element's HTML attributes as name and value?

5) My template's code is exactly what I've pasted - do I need to make it a valid HTML structure with head, body etc.? Do I have to attach `<script>` with AngularJS? I've done that, but once again, no change.

6) The usage scenario for the whole story is to choose a concrete generator from a drop-down list and display it's constructor params in the specified way. So it has to regenerate HTML with a generator's change. I assume that it's done in the ng-repeat loop but please confirm that.

Thank you very, very much for your input! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you both guys for your help! Unfortunately, I can't mark any of the given answer as correct, because I have to mixed them in order to get what I was looking for.

I wouldn't elaborate here, let me just share with you the **final code**:

```
<!-- container -->
<p ng-repeat="param in selectedGenerator.constructorParams">
  <constructor-param param="param"></constructor-param>
</p>

<!-- template -->
<div ng-switch="param.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
        <input type="number" name={{param.type}} min="0" value={{param.value}}>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
        <select ng-if="param.value" name={{param.type}}>
            <option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-if="!param.value" name={{param.type}}>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="false">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="String">
        <input type="text" name={{param.type}} value={{param.value}}>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="Double">
        <input type="number" name={{param.type}} step="0.01" min="0" value={{param.value}}>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the directive, you both get it right:

```
app.directive("constructorParam", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      param: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/html_templates/constructor_param_template.html'
  };
});
```

Once again - thank you very much, I wouldn't solve this problem so quickly without your help!

Answer (score 2):

When you do `param : '@'` that's a "text binding". That's useful in case you want to tell Angular to not interpret what you're binding to your attribute as a property on the scope but rather as a string directly.

So if you'd do

`<my-custom-directive param="hello"></my-custom-directive>`

Then in your directive, `param` would be equal to the the string `"hello"`. While if you bind to `param` using two-way binding `param : '='`, then Angular would look for the `hello` property on the scope instead of taking it as a string literal.

In your case, when you do `param="{{param}}"` Angular is first unpacking "param" by looking at the scope, into a string literal, then it creates the binding. So even though this might have worked if `param` was a string, in your case it's an Object, so I don't think it will play well. So I would just do a direct binding to it (see my final code below).

In your directive template, you're also using a few Angular directive which expect a scope binding, so I would try to bind without the curly brackets. See my example code below.

```js
app.directive("constructorParam", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      param: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/html_templates/constructor_param_template.html'
  };
});
```

```html
<!-- container -->
<p ng-repeat="param in selectedGenerator.constructorParams">
  <constructor-param param="{{param}}"></constructor-param>
</p>

<!-- TEMPLATE -->

<div ng-switch="param.type">
  <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
    <input type="number" ng-attr-name="param.type" min="0" ng-attr-value="param.value">
  </div>

  <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
    <select ng-if="param.value" ng-attr-name="param.type">
            <option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>

    <select ng-if="!param.value" ng-attr-name="param.type">
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="false">No</option>
        </select>
  </div>

  <div ng-switch-when="String">
    <input type="text" ng-attr-name="param.type" ng-attr-value="param.value">
  </div>

  <div ng-switch-when="Double">
    <input type="number" ng-attr-name="param.type" step="0.01" min="0" ng-attr-value="param.value">
  </div>
</div>
```

If it still doesn't work, let me know so I can try it in a CodePen.

Answer (score 1):

1) No, you need to remove the curly brackets when passing the values to directive

`<constructor-param param="param"></constructor-param>`

2,3) in directive use `=` instead of `@`. Because `@` take string value of the parameter and `=` take the parameter value

```
scope: {
    param: '='
},
```

4) if you need to bind data then use `ng-model` instead of `ng-attr`

5) You don't need to add html or body tag inside `constructor_param_template.html` template.

6) ng-repeat does that. once the array get updated it will dynamically update the DOM

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z4xnNojnfhaFwbITiVVQ?p=preview)